# Linqtosql query: top dates.. total numbers.. groupby orderby.. = fun stuff :)

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

Here is something I'm working on at the moment.

I have a database with a Debt table (types of debt, visa/mastercard etc) and a monthly amount table (monthly amounts of each type of debt December Visa bill amount outstanding, etc).

How would I use LinQ to query against the db to get a total amount of debt based on the last reported monthly debt amount (not necessarily the current month in all cases).

So far, I have tried this:

```
(from M in MonthlyAmounts
group M by new {M.MonthYear.Month, M.MonthYear.Year} into D
orderby D.Key.Month descending
select D).Take(1);
```

Which is great for listing the amounts broken down by month, but it doesn't solve my problem of a debt amount not being reported for the current month yet.
So:
Give me all the debts from the most current reporting period and total them up (a list of them would be nice as well).

On a side note, if it matters, I'm using EntityFramework against the SQL db.  Also, "MonthYear" is a DateTime.

Comment: I don't understand "get a total amount of debt based on the last reported monthly debt amount" and it would be nice if we wouldn't have to guess where the debt amount is stored.

Comment: Sorry Guys, I suppose I should have added more of the db structure... though the first answer below looks like it might work (trying now).

Comment: I have 2 tables one is a list of debt types (Id and Name), the other is a list of debt entries for each debt (DebtId int32, "MonthYear" datetime, "DebtAmount" decimal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the structure of your `MonthAmounts` table is like so:

```
public class MonthlyAmount
{
    public DateTime MonthYear { get; set;}
    public string DebtType { get; set;}
    public decimal DebtAmount { get; set;}
}
```

If wasn't clear from your question whether or not there will be only one record for a given debt type & month/year combination or not. And since you have explicitly said that `MonthYear` is of `DateTime` type I'm going to assume that there could be any number of records for a given debt type per month. This kind of fits the thinking that you would have a table of individual transactions that you need to group together. If I'm wrong could you please clarify.

So here are the queries required:

```
var codedMonthlyAmounts =
    from ma in MonthlyAmounts
    let MonthCode =
        ma.MonthYear.Year * 12
        + ma.MonthYear.Month
        - 1
    select new
    {
        MonthCode,
        ma.DebtType,
        ma.DebtAmount,
    };

var latest = 
    from cma in codedMonthlyAmounts
    group cma by cma.DebtType into gcmas
    let DebtType = gcmas.Key
    let current = gcmas
        .GroupBy(gcma => gcma.MonthCode)
        .OrderBy(ggcma => ggcma.Key)
        .Last()
    let DebtAmount = current.Sum(c => c.DebtAmount)
    let monthCode = current.Key
    let year = monthCode / 12
    let month = monthCode % 12 + 1
    let MonthYear = new DateTime(year, month, 1)
    select new MonthlyAmount()
    {
        DebtType = DebtType,
        MonthYear = MonthYear,
        DebtAmount = DebtAmount,
    };
```

If you'd like to test if this works, use this code:

```
var MonthlyAmounts = new List<MonthlyAmount>();

var now = DateTime.Now;

MonthlyAmounts.Add(new MonthlyAmount()
    { MonthYear = now,
        DebtType = "Visa", DebtAmount = 1.2M, });
MonthlyAmounts.Add(new MonthlyAmount()
    { MonthYear = now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(2)),
        DebtType = "Visa", DebtAmount = 42.0M, });
MonthlyAmounts.Add(new MonthlyAmount()
    { MonthYear = now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(31)),
        DebtType = "MC", DebtAmount = 50.95M, });
MonthlyAmounts.Add(new MonthlyAmount()
    { MonthYear = now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(33)),
        DebtType = "Visa", DebtAmount = 3.1415M, });

//insert above `codedMonthlyAmounts` & `latest` queries here.

var format = "{0} @ {1:MMM} {1:yyyy} = {2:#,##0.00}";
foreach (var x in latest)
{
    Console.WriteLine(format,
        x.DebtType,
        x.MonthYear,
        x.DebtAmount);
}

Console.WriteLine("Total = {0:#,##0.00}",
    latest.Sum(l => l.DebtAmount));
```

The output for the test code is:

```
Visa @ Dec 2010 = 43.20 
MC @ Nov 2010 = 50.95 
Total = 94.15
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted or not.

Comment: Testing now, but this looks right on the money (no pun intended :) )

Comment: Any idea why the second query would throw this: {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,<>f__AnonymousType1`3[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Decimal]] 
Last[IGrouping`2](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,<>f__AnonymousType1`3[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Decimal]]])' 
method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Comment: @CraigF - You get these kinds of errors when EF (or LINQ-to-SQL, etc) doesn't know how to translate the LINQ statement into a SQL query. LINQ-to-Objects can run these queries so all you need to do is force the query to run against objects and not the database. Just add `.ToArray()` to `codedMonthlyAmounts` on the `latest` query and you'll be good.

Comment: Sometimes I don't know where my head is at.. of course, thank you.. and yes, that works perfectly.  (.. and after reading up on "Let" I'm not sure how I missed that gem)